# Facing difficulty to use pdfform.js in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I would like to use a pdfform.js library(package) within react app. I have tried by using the npm [pdfform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfform.js) but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

https://github.com/phihag/pdfform.js

Comment: You can try bundled version of pdfjs library with react. Link here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bundled-es-modules/pdfjs-dist

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo, maybe it will help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>pddform.js demo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://phihag.github.io/pdfform.js/docs/demo.css" />
</head>

<body>
 <div class="error"></div>
 <form class="url_form">
  <div>Upload a PDF form file: <label><input type="file" name="file" /></label></div>

  <label>or download one: <input type="text" size="40" value="Spielberichtsbogen_2BL.pdf" name="url" /><button role="submit">Download</button></label>
 </form>

 <form class="cur_file"></form>

 <form class="lib_form">
  PDF library:
  <label><input type="radio" name="pdflib" value="minipdf" checked="checked" />minipdf</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="pdflib" value="pdf.js" />PDF.js</label>
 </form>

 <form class="fill_form"><button class="fill" disabled="disabled">Fill and download PDF</button></form>

 <form class="list_form">
 </form>

 <div class="loading">Loading (this may take a while since PDF.js is gigantic)</div>

 <!-- In a real-life scenario, you want to chose EITHER minipdf (smaller) -->
 <script src="https://phihag.github.io/pdfform.js/minipdf.js"></script>

 <!-- .. OR pdf.js (huge, but better compatibility).
pdf.worker.js is slightly modified to export the actual classes we care about -->
 <script src="https://phihag.github.io/pdfform.js/customlibs/pdf.worker.js"></script>
 <script src="https://phihag.github.io/pdfform.js/minipdf_js.js"></script>


 <!-- pako and pdfform.js are required either way -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pako/1.0.3/pako.min.js" integrity="sha256-X7u/eQo6oIgWqc5jOmTjQn3loM8Lse0ock76Gkkn/Ro="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://phihag.github.io/pdfform.js/pdfform.js"></script>

 <!-- FileSaver.js is just needed for the demo, although you'll probably use it in some form as well -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.0.0/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://phihag.github.io/pdfform.js/docs/demo.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this demo but somehow it's not working in react.